# Mssql 2012 with PHP & Mysql to Mssql migration

Tags: php, sql-server, apache, xampp, sqlsrv

I'm just migrated database from mysql to mssql 2012. After that, i followed below steps to connect with mssql.

I have installed Xampp in my local machine (windows 7 64 bit os).

```
PHP Version 5.5.11

Apache Version  Apache/2.4.9 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1g PHP/5.5.11
```

Separately installed `MSSql 2012`.

Now i want to connect php with mssql 2012.
I got `Fatal error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect() .`

Added php_sql_54.ts.dll and enabled in php.ini. But it says

```
php startup: sqlsrv: unable to initiate module module complied with module API=20100525
php complied with module API=20121212 these options need to match
```

then I added php_sql_55_ts.dll in Ext folder.

Next error i got :

```
The program can't start because MSVCP110.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinsatalling the program
```

Installed C++ tool from microsoft site. Then the final error is :

```
PHP Startup: unable to load dynamic library php_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll is not a valid win32 application.
```

How to solve it? I need to connect mssql with PHP.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check weather your os is 32/64 bit . Install C++ based on that.
if you have installed this version it will not work :

```
Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable (x64)
```

or

```
Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable (x86)
```

Comment: my os is 64 bit window 7. I installed lot of Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable X86 packages.

Comment: you have to istall  Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable X64.

Comment: Already done. and also i have installed mssql 2012. This may be reason for problem.?

Comment: It may be the problem . Give it a try.

Comment: just install visual c++ and run start the sql again . If it shows same error . Try reinstalling sql server.

Comment: sqlserver 2012 is required? or we can do without it. Because we are using some dll files.